# composer removes diectories in web/bundles

Tags: svn, symfony, composer-php

I'm new to Symfony2 and composer. I normally manage all project code in svn, either by committing framework code to svn as well or using linked repositories. I understand that most Symfony bundles use git for revision control.

I'm having an odd issue happening when installing new bundles with composer. For example to install FOSUserBundle, I add to composer.json:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
```

Then I run

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

This works fine, but it removes all folders from web/bundles, for example

```
~       web/bundles/framework
~       web/bundles/sensiodistribution
```

Is this a configuration problem in composer or some sort of incompatibility with svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal that these folders are regenerated during update. This is part of the post-update/-install scripts.

The recommended .gitignore-file contains web/bundles, so I guess you should add the folder to your .svnignore as well. Alternatively you yould remove the post post-update/-install hooks from your composer.json. But since the assets are copied from the bundles Resources/public/ to the web/ folder in order for them to be accessible, you would have to alias them in your vhost or something...

In short, just add web/bundles to your .svnignore

Comment: Supplemental information can be found in the chapter [How to Create and store a Symfony2 Project in Subversion](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html) in the Symfony cookbook.