# Composer removes web/bundles even if in .gitignore

Tags: symfony, composer-php, assets, symfony-3.3

Ok, starting from this morning **composer update** removes all the assets from web/bundles.
It never did it before. I've searched here and i've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071778/composer-removes-diectories-in-web-bundles) so i've checked my .gitignore (I can't find a .svnignore), here it is. 
How can i solve?

```
/app/config/parameters.yml
/build/
/phpunit.xml
/var/*
!/var/cache
/var/cache/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!/var/logs
/var/logs/*
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!/var/sessions
/var/sessions/*
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
!var/SymfonyRequirements.php
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
```

**[ EDIT ]**

This is my composer.json, it did never delete the content of web/bundles folder. The only difference is that it upgraded symfony from 3.3.2 to 3.3.3

```
{
    "name": "app/demo",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "commerceguys/addressing": "^1.0.0-beta3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "egulias/email-validator": "^2.1",
        "fdisotto/partita-iva": "^3.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "jstayton/google-maps-geocoder": "^2.4",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.1",
        "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.7",
        "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "usu/codice-fiscale": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Composer and git perform different functions.  [Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).  [Git is a version control system](https://git-scm.com/). You are likely observing the result of post-update command in `composer.json`.  Provide your `composer.json`.

Comment: @geoB added, thank you. Yes is a result of post-update, maybe installAssets. But why it started now?

Comment: Maybe i should move all my public resources in app/Resources/public folder?